# accesing attribute of anobject from another object that belong to the same class

Tags: java, oop

Hi I'm not very good in OOP, Sorry if anyone have asked same question . Right now I have problem in acccesing attribute of an object from another object, where both object belong to one object

```
public abstract class GameClient (){  
protected ClientRegistry registry;  
..   
}


public class MarketClient extends GameClient {   
public Auctioneer auctioneer = null;  
public Specialist specialist;  
...  
((GenericDoubleAuctioneer) auctioneer).setRegistry((MarketRegistry) registry);
specialist = registry.addSpecialist(clientId);  
}


public class Specialist extends AccountHolder() {  
public Specialist(final String id) {
        this(id, null);  
...   
}


public interface Auctioneer extends QuoteProvider (){  
public MarketRegistry getRegistry();  
public List configuration  
...  }

  public class DailyAssessmentReport(){  
protected void calculateProfits() {  
final Specialist specialists[] = GameController.getInstance().getRegistry().getSpecialists();  
//later, I'll get the ID of each specialist from specialists[];  
...  
...  
public Map< specialistID, List, Score> Result;  
//this Map contains specialistID , auctioneer.configuration, score  
}
```

What I want to do is to make a MAP which consist (specialistID, auctioneer.configuration, profit). My question is how could I access/ get value of  `Auctioneer.configuration` from `DailyAssessmentReport`class ?

I really appreciate your answer

Comment: Please make clear what you mean with "[...] acccesing attribute of an object from another object, where both object belong to one object".

Comment: I have a `MarketClient` object, this `MarketClient` has attributes which are `specialist` and `auctioneer` (both are different class), somehow I can get `specialist` objects from another class, how can I can access one of the `auctioneer` attribute when the only thing I have is the `specialists` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map, e.g. a HashMap for your purpose. Please note that maps map from one object to another object. They do not map from one object to two other objects like what you try to do in your example. However, you can still achieve your goal by storing the two destination objects in a common container object (e.g. ArrayList or a 2-element array) and then mapping to the container object. Example:

```
HashMap<String, Object[]> specialistIdToContainerObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();

// get two objects which should be looked up later through the map, based on specialist ID
Specialist specialist = ...;
Auctioneer auctioneer = ...;

// create container object to hold the two objects to which we want to map
Object[] containerObject = new Object[2];
containerObject[0] = specialist;
containerObject[1] = auctioneer;

// store the container object in the map
specialistIdToContainerObjectMap.put(specialist.getId(), containerObject);
```

You can then later look up the container object and extract the two referenced objects from it:

```
// get a specialist id from somewhere, e.g. by doing someSpecialist.getId()
String specialistId = ...;

// look up the container object from the map
Object[] containerObject = specialistIdToContainerObjectMap.get(specialistId);

// extract the specialist and the auctioneer from the container object
Specialist specialist = (Specialist) containerObject[0];
Auctioneer auctioneer = (Auctioneer) containerObject[1];
```

I hope this helps you. If not, e.g. because I misunderstood your question, please provide feedback so we can try to find the right solution for you.